# Constructing an anisotropic crystal in WulffPack

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-simulation-environment, wulffpack

I am trying to create an $\ce{LiFePO4}$ crystal in WulffPack. I have the surface energies of seven different surfaces from the paper [1]. When I input the same to WulffPack, it creates a structure comprising of just the lowest energy surface, as shown:

```py
from wulffpack import SingleCrystal
from ase.io import write
from ase.build import bulk
 
surface_energies = {(1, 0, 0): 0.66, (0, 1, 0): 0.64,(0, 0, 1): 0.97, 
                    (1, 0, 1): 0.62, (0, 1, 1): 0.76,(1, 1, 0): 1.30,
                    (1, 1, 1): 0.85, (2, 0, 1): 0.52, (3, 0, 1): 0.62}
 
prim = bulk('Li', 'orthorhombic', a=10.4363, b=6.0491, c=4.7546)
particle = SingleCrystal(surface_energies, prim) 

particle.view() 
particle.write('LFP.obj')
```

[image: LiFePO4_MyStructure]

But the structure given in the paper has five surfaces as shown:
[image: LiFePO4_Wang et.al.]

I am not able to understand why there is a difference, or where I am making a mistake. I would appreciate any kind of help related to this. Thanks!

1. First-principles study of surface properties of LiFePO4: Surface energy, structure, Wulff shape, and surface redox potential
   October 2007 Physical Review B 76(16):165435 DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevB.76.165435

Comment: Welcome to the site! It will help other users to answer your question if you include the code you used to generate your figure.

Comment: When I tried your code, I got a different result, but it still did not match the paper. I don't know much about these Wulff shapes, but will it be affected by specifying all the atoms in the crystal? As of now, you are just using $\ce{Li}$ in specifying the bulk crystal; do you need to include the other elements somehow (I found that `bulk` will only accept a single element, but ASE likely has ways of specifying a more general crystal).

Comment: @Tyberius yes, the code I have shared creates a structure in Wulffpack containing the (001) surface which has high surface energy. Also, the (100) surface is missing, which has much lower energy than (001). I tried creating the same in Wulffman, there the (001) surface was not part of the structure but again, (100) was missing. I too think that the issue lies with specifying all atoms in the crystal and not just Li, but couldn't find anything in the ASE documentation. Would be great if I could get some leads on this!

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/spacegroup/spacegroup.html. Since you know the formula, spacegroup, and parameters, all you should need is the basis.

Comment: @Tyberius thank you so much! I can visualize the atoms using ase.spacegroup.crystal but I'm not able to incorporate it into ase.build.bulk. Looks like it accepts only single atoms already present in its database, and not custom-made crystal structures.

Comment: Does it need to be passed through `bulk` or could Wulffpack accept just the result from `crystal`?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you so much for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! By the way, how did you find this site?

Comment: Since it's been awhile since Tyberius asked you for clarification, I wonder if you've had a chance to think about that yet? How are you doing with this problem, have you managed to figure it out? Shall we close the question to allow users to focus on questions that might be more urgent in nature?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to give an answer.